# ADD certificate in HTTP Header

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to add a Certificate in http header. My questions are :

1. Do we have to send it as byte Array? or as a String?
2. If yes , the toString method of java.securit.PublicKey does it build
   a good string representation?
3. Isn't it too long to be inserted in an http header or not? Thanks

Code :

```
public byte []   getCertificate() throws IOException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    if (Configuration.getSignaturekeyStoreLocation()==null || ewalletConfiguration.getSignaturekeyStoreLocation().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Keystore url must not be null");
        }
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(Configuration.getSignaturekeyStoreLocation());
        char[] keyPassword = ewalletConfiguration.getSignaturekeyStorePassword().toCharArray();
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        //keyStore Password
        keystore.load(is, keyPassword);
        //
        final Certificate cert = (Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(Configuration.getSignatureCertificateAlias());

        return  cert.getEncoded();
}``
```

`

Answer (score 0):

There are different purposes why there would be a certificate in the header, so it would be simpler if you'd explain the use case.

> Do we have to send it as byte Array? or as a String?

HTTP headers are always a string, I'd assume you will need to use base64 encoding.

> If yes , the toString method of java.securit.PublicKey does it build a good string representation?

No, the public key is only a public key, not the whole certificate (a certificate contains the public key). The simplest way to get a (x509) certificate representation is using [getEncoded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/cert/Certificate.html#getEncoded--) method

> Isn't it too long to be inserted in an http header or not? Thanks

It may. Usually http servers are having certain header buffer (e.g. apache tomat has/had default 8kB buffer, IIS 16kB) so if the returned encoded response would be larger, the server may return an error response. Even I know some clients / browsers are having different limits.

I'd be curious what you want to achieve, maybe there is a more robust way, such as sending necessary certificate in a payload or send the certificate signature only